# Multiplying set of user inputs?

Tags: java

This java exercise wants me to ask the user to enter how many values they would like to multiply (n), then have the user enter those numbers.  After that I am supposed to multiply the user inputs and that is the part where I am stuck.

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeometricMean {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, i;
        String value;
        double product;
        System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you want to process");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a value");
            value = sc.nextLine();
        }
        product = (i * i);
        //If i did know what the correct product formula is I would write:
        System.out.println("The product is" + product);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's much easier to create a `total` variable and set it to 1. After each value you scan, you just multiply the input with `total` and assign it to `total`: `total = total * input;` or `total *= input`.

Comment: you should set `product` to 1 before you execute your program.

Comment: after that, you just multiply it by the value.  `product = product * value`

Comment: You should have `value` as `int` (maybe use `value = sc.nextInt()`), and then do what @HamZa says. If you have Java8, then you can use `Stream` and `reduce` to have the entire thing done in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently doing nothing with the input. Also, you are multiplying the amount of numbers you want the user to enter, instead of multiplying the actual numbers.

You could first create an array, using input from the user to specify how many indexes:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
double[] numbers = new double[n];
```

Then loop through the array, receiving a value for each index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
     numbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();
```

After that, loop again and multiply each number:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
double product = 1.0;
for(double number : numbers)
     product *= number;
```

Although, it'll be easier to just add to the product as you receive the numbers:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
double product = 1.0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     product *= sc.nextDouble();
```

As a full application, using the easier alternative:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeometricMean {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you want to process");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        double product = 1.0;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a value");
            product *= sc.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("The product is" + product);
    }
}
```